# Get a value based on certain condition(xml)

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm new to xml and learning, please assist me with below challenge.

what's the xpath to get an email of an employee based on certain tag/condition

Example: get work email of an employee where id is "100" or get personal email of an employee where role is "Manager"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Employees>
    <Employee>
        <id>100</id>
        <email>
            <personal>tomy@personal.uk</personal>
            <work>tom@abcorp.in</work>
        </email>
        <age>29</age>
        <name>Tom</name>
        <gender>Male</gender>
        <role>Assistant</role>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
        <id>200</id>
        <email>
            <personal>abc@personal.com</personal>
            <work>meghna@abcorp.in</work>
        </email>
        <age>40</age>
        <name>Meghna</name>
        <gender>Female</gender>
        <role>Manager</role>
    </Employee>
</Employees>
```

Comment: please post what have you tried so far

Comment: tried "//work" which returns all work email ids, but sure how can I anchor with id to get particular email id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to navigate the structure adding the conditions, in the example you mentioned in comments it would be like this:

```
//Employee[id="100"]/email/work
```

similarly to get the personal email for role manager:

```
//Employee[role="Manager"]/email/personal
```

Comment: thanks for your effort, it worked as expected.